# What types of indicators are there for the end of a string when tokenizing a sentence?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to take a string holding a sentence and break it up by words to add to a linked list class called wordList.

When dealing with strings in C++, what is the indicator that you have reached the end of a string? Searched here are found that c strings are null terminated and some are indicated with a '\0' but these solutions give me errors.

I know there are other ways to do this (like scanning through individual characters) but I am fuzzy on how to implement.

```
void lineScan( string line)     // Adds words to wordList from line of a file
{
    istringstream iss(line);
    string lineWord;
    getline(iss, lineWord, ' ');

    wrds.addWords( lineWord );

    while( lineWord!= NULL )
    {
        getline(iss, lineWord, ' ');
        wrds.addWords( lineWord );
    }

}
```

Comment: `string::end`? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/end/

Comment: Your function accepts its sole argument by value, which is unnecessary here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to skip all whitespace, not use a single space as separator (your code will read empty tokens).

But you're not really dealing with strings here, and in particular not with C strings.
Since you're using `istringstream`, you're looking for the end of a stream, and it works like all instreams.

```
void lineScan(string line)     // Adds words to wordList from line of a file
{
    istringstream iss(line);
    string word;
    while (iss >> word)
    {
        wrds.addWords(word);
    }
}
```